# traefik with option usebindportip does not work as described

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, traefik-ingress

i use traefik with docker with option `--providers.docker.usebindportip=true`

i want use this variant then request port = endpoint port **without add port label** in container:
[image]

i try run whoami container from manual with only 1 label:

```
traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(whoami.lan)
```

and in traefik log i receive error about port missing:

```
time="2022-01-03T06:22:40Z" level=error msg="service \"whoami-traefik-test\" error: port is missing" container=whoami-traefik-test-
```

What is problem ?

Comment: i dont know usebindportip but you need backticks here : ```rule=Host(`whoami.lan`)```

Comment: can you provide the labels you put on your container ? did you set this label : traefik.http.services.<service_name>.loadbalancer.server.port ?

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO i have backticks , its problem stackoverflow editor

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO  all right. with the 'usebindportip'  option, I can not specify 'traefik.http.services.<service_name>.loadbalancer.server.port' as it is written in the manual